# How to create widget which would display products with the same name as the product on page?

Tags: widget, magento2.3.0, name

I am new to Magento and I need to create widget which will dynamically take name of the product on which page he would be and show all the products with the same name as this product, for example:

> Product name : shoe1
>
> Show all products with name of shoe1

It's like normal **Catalog Product List** with condition *all categories* AND simple check if the names are the same.

Currently I have no clue where to start. I have created one custom  widget for banners but this is too much for me but need to be done. I could send request to the database and retrieve what I need but I don't know how to show swatches or add to card button and it feels like overkill.

It's my first question, normally I don't do it but I am in need. **Pleas help me**.